# MSMQ private queue messaging accross servers

Tags: msmq

I have a hosted server which relies heavily on MSMQ for messaging.
Without getting into specifics of the overall system, I now have a private queue which I need it's content sent to a private queue on another server.

The other server is not on the same physical network, but a plan can be made with a VPN or using public IP addresses.

I could develop my own system for doing this, but it feels like I am reinventing the wheel.
I would think MSMQ to MSMQ to be a build in functionality

Answer (score 0):

You will need to write an app to read messages from the private queue on the hosted server and send copies of them to the private queue on the other server.